# How to Trigger a Error from a VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I need to trigger(return) an error event from a VBA function, then the calling function of this function can trigger On Error Go to call.
E.g

```
function Test()
 On Error Go to myError:
       TestErr()
 Exit Function

 myerror:
    Test = "Error Triggered"
End Function

Function TestErr()
    ?? 'How to Trigger error here
End Function
```

Thank You

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Err.Raise 5, "optional error source" , "optional error description"

MSDN reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164019%28office.10%29.aspx#odc_tentipsvba_topic3

Comment: I think there should be two commas after the '5'.  The second argument is for Source, the third for Description.

Comment: According to the referenced page it should be: Err.Raise vbObjectError + 5, "optional error source" , "optional error description".  

But either way I don't see my custom error on the worksheet.  I used this to raise an error when the user passes incompatible arguments to a custom function.  The cell just reports "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type" if I enter values that invoke the 'Err.Raise' code.  Neither source nor description are visible.  Not sure I see the point.  1/0 does the same.

Comment: @bielawski The two parameters are used with the error handler in VBA, via Err.Source and Err.Description. Using the built in error code of 5 would be appropriate if the error was "Invalid procedure call or argument" (which is the Err.Description that goes with Err.Number 5).

Answer (score 8):

Dirty way: `1 / 0`

Comment: Haha!! I initially thought about this when I saw the question

Comment: The message will be unhelpful.

Answer (score 4):

Not what you asked, but note that if you want to return an error to a cell from a UDF, use CVErr.  Like

```
Test = CVErr(xlErrNA)
```

to return #NA